# iOS 7 - Black preview screen in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

Using the below code to launch the image picker to capture the image. 
 Can any one help out to close this issue...

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {        

    if (self.camera)
    {
        self.camera = nil;
    }

    self.camera = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.camera.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.camera.allowsEditing = NO;
    self.camera.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:self.camera animated:YES completion:NULL];


}
```

Comment: Before launching the UIImagePickerController if you have any GCD in background might be a reason for this issue. In my code have GCD before launching the UIImagePickerController, now removed the GCD it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Before launching the UIImagePickerController if you have any GCD in background might be a reason for this issue. In my code have GCD before launching the UIImagePickerController, now removed the GCD it's working fine.